# Using QApplication::setStyleSheet to override QSS attributes set in Qt

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I created a button in `Qt` and gave it the `QSS` attribute `background-color: gray;`, while my external stylesheet has set the `QSS` attribute of the same button to `background-color: blue;`. When I run the application the button is gray, even though the style sheet is applied *after* the `QWidget::show()` is called and just before `QApplication::exec()`, as shown below:

```
MyWidget w;
w.show();
...
app.setStyleSheet("..."); // contents of external stylesheet
return app.exec();
```

Is it possible to have `QApplication::setStyleSheet()` override the `QSS` attributes assigned to a Widget in `Qt`.

Comment: Your button should be blue, because app.setStyleSheet should redesign widget, can you show your full stylesheets?

Comment: @Olumide Are you sure that your stylesheet is loaded correctly?

Comment: @N1ghtLight I am sure the stylesheet is loaded correctly. Actually, I am opening the stylesheet file reading it and writing its contents to `QApplication::setStyleSheet()`

Comment: @Olumide, please post here the piece of your external stylesheet where you define button background-color

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible to override the `QSS` attributes the way you want, and trust me, you don't want to. It is not the order in which you call `setStyleSheet` that matters. It is the hierarchy that matters first. The call order matters only on widgets which are situated on the same level of the hierarchy.

The reason is that the widget has its internal style rules defined which override the parent's style thus the application style in your case. It is a hierarchy that is respected. You can look at this in the following way:

Say you have a `QWidget` with the following child hierarchy:

```
QWidget
  |__QPushButton
  |
  |__QFrame
  |  |
  |  |_QListView
  |
  |__QProgressBar
```

Let's say you want to customize the `background-color` to all the widgets in your hierarchy. If the call to `QApplication::setStyleSheet()` would overwrite the stylesheet properties for the children, it would be impossible for you to set a custom style for your children. That's why child widget's `QSS` properties overwrite parent widget's `QSS` properties.

Look at it like the usual way to look at widgets. `QPushButton` is shown on top of `QWidget`. `QFrame` is shown on top of `QWidget`. `QListView` is also shown on top of `QWidget`. Styles apply the same way.

What I recommend doing is having only one external `QSS` file in which you define everything you want.

**EDIT:**
As `N1ghtLight` pointed out `QSS` preserves the class inheritance hierarchy so if you set a property for a class all its derived classes will inherit that property. For example if you have the following stylesheet:

```
QAbstractButton {
    background-color: red;
}

QPushButton {
    color: blue;
}
```

All `QPushButtons` will have the background color `red` and the text color `blue` as the `QPushButton` inherits the `background-color` property value from `QAbstractButton` which is its ancestor while `QAbstractButton`s which are not `QPushButton`s will have the background color `red` but the text color will remain unchanged.

The example above used a type selector. You can apply the style to specific objects by using different selector types. You can see different selector types [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types).

Comment: Will be nice if you will extend your answer with explanation how stylesheets provides possibility to define styles for base classes, for example, QAbstractButton, and these styles are inherited in inheritance hierarchy :)